# Matlab : Matrix indexing Logic

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix-indexing

i am doing very simple Matrix indexing examples  . where code is  as give below

```
>> A=[ 1 2 3 4 ; 5 6 7 8 ; 9 10 11  12  ]

A =

     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
     9    10    11    12

>> A(end, end-2)   

ans =

    10

>> A(2:end, end:-2:1)

ans =

     8     6
    12    10
```

here i am bit confused  . when i use   `A(end, end-2)`    it takes difference of two  till first column and when there is  just one  column  left there is no  further processing , but when i use   `A(2:end, end:-2:1)` it takes  `6 10`  but how does it print  `8 12`  while there is just one column  left and we have to take difference of two from right to left , Pleas someone explain this simple point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selection `A(end, end-2)` reads: *take elements in last row of A that appear in column 4(end)-2=2*.

The selection `A(2:end, end:-2:1)` similarly reads: *take elements in rows 2 to 4(end) and starting from last column going backwards in jumps of two, i.e. 4 then 2.*

To check the indexing, simply substitute the `end` with `size(A,1)` or `size(A,2)` if respectively found in the row and col position.

Answer (score 0):

First the general stuff: `end` is just a placeholder for an index, namely the last position in a given array dimension. For instance, for an arbitrary array `A(end,1)` will pick the last element in column 1, and `A(1,end)` will pick the last element in the first row.

In your example, `A(end, end-2)` picks an element in the last row two columns before the last one.

To interpret a statement such as

```
A(2:end, end:-2:1)
```

it might help to substitute `end` with the actual index of the last row/column elements, so this is equivalent to

```
A(2:3, 4:-2:1)
```

Furthermore `4:-2:1` is equivalent to the list `4,2` since we are instructing to make the list starting at 4, decreasing in steps of 2, up to (minimum) 1. So this is equivalent to

```
A([2 3],[4 2])
```

Finally, the following combination of indices is implied by `A([2 3],[4 2])`:

```
 A(2,4)   A(2,2)
 A(3,4)   A(3,2)
```